# Is RSA SecurID suitable for a third party authentication app for Salesforce 2FA?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I am interested if one can use [RSA SecurId](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsa.securidapp&hl=en_GB&gl=US) as a Third Party Authenticator app with Salesforce for 2FA.

As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=add_time-based_token.htm&type=5 and https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/white-papers/2fa-admin-rollout-guide.pdf,

> 'You can use any authenticator app that supports the TOTP algorithm (IETF RFC 6238), such as Salesforce Authenticator for iOS, Salesforce Authenticator for Android, or Google Authenticator'.

As per the RSA community link [here](https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-80665),

> The RSA Authenticate app is a multi-factor authentication option that works in conjunction with the RSA SecurID Access Cloud Authentication Service and provides several options for authentication, including biometrics and FIDO tokens.
>
> Neither of the apps support TOTP, and the apps cannot be used without their corresponding RSA servers'.

So, that implies that RSA SecurId **cannot** be used for 2FA with Salesforce? Has anyone had any success with RSA SecurID as 2FA with Salesforce?

Comment: We have a number of clients using it, so yes it can be done. You're thinking that a RSA authenticator (hardware or software token) can be used in a plug-and-play manner similar to Google or Salesforce authenticator. That is not the case. SecurID is fundamentally a different animal, it uses its own protocols and requires RSA server software. The overall solution architecture that involves RSA SecurID and RSA's own software can and does work with Salesforce. How? It depends. Some options are outlined in RSA's [whitepaper](https://www.rsa.com/content/dam/en/use-case/modern-mfa-for-salesforce.pdf)

Comment: OK, so an RSA Authenticator cannot be used for 2FA with Salesforce however, other RSA services certainly can be used with Salesforce for MFA?

Comment: You can authenticate via RSA SecurID to RSA "app", that includes RSA Authenticate app. If you integrate the other RSA piece(s) with Salesforce, the overall solution from end-user perspective will mean that SecurID can be used to sign in to Salesforce. Doc: https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-99940