# Can RSA SecurID be used as Salesforce MFA?

Tags: security, mfa, multi-factor-authentication

Next year MFA will be required ([Salesforce MFA Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352937&type=1)) and the customer has RSA SecurID  as 2FA for other applications, We would like to know if we can use SecurID  as a third-party authenticator app for MFA?

Thank you for any information.

Comment: See comments in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331180/is-rsa-securid-suitable-for-a-third-party-authentication-app-for-salesforce-2fa